# Was the Angolan style of music called kizomba inspired by Kassav'?

Tags: history, genre

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N57gkB4Q60s) [French] claims that [kizomba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kizomba) was created after [zouk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zouk) creator [Kassav'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kassav) inspired Angolan artists.

On the opposite, [Eduardo Paim](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduardo_Pa%C3%ADm) has [claimed](https://web.archive.org/web/20130927200128/http://www.opais.net/pt/dossier/?det=21059) [Portuguese] that kizomba was [created independently in Angola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kizomba#Origin_and_evolution), inspired by Afro Sound Star, then brought to Europe where it was confused with zouk.

Which one is right?

Comment: Perhaps this question would be a good fit for the yet not existing [Music Fans site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46533/music-fans)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this Kizomba site](http://www.kizombalove.com/Kizombalove,45):

> Kizomba music was born in Angola (in Luanda) in the 80’s following the
>   influences of traditional Semba music (the predecessor of Samba from
>   Brazil) and Zouk music from the groupe Kassav from the French
>   Caribbean Island Guadeloupe. On this basis, Kizomba music emerged as a
>   more modern music genre with a sensual touch mixed with African
>   rhythm. Unlike Semba, Kizomba music is characterised by a slower and
>   usually very romantic rhythm. Given that Angola is a former Portuguese
>   colony, Portuguese is the principal language spoken in Angola and
>   thus, also most Kizomba songs are sung in Portuguese. However, Kizomba
>   songs of the very beginning were song in Kimbundu and in other
>   National languages of Angola. Famous Angolan Kizomba singers include
>   Bonga (Semba, traditional music), André Mingas (traditional music),
>   Liceu Vieira Dias, Neide Van-Dúnem (Semba, tradional music), Don Kikas
>   (Semba, Kizomba), Calo Pascoal (Kizomba), Heavy C. (Semba, Kizomba),
>   Puto Portugues (Semba), Maya Cool (Kizomba, Semba), Matias Damasio
>   (Kizomba, Semba), Rei Helder (Semba), and Irmãos Verdades (Kizomba).